# Implementing an IIR filter in Pytorch using RNN with no nonlinearity

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

Is it possible to implement an RNN layer with no nonlinearity in Pytorch like in Keras where one can set the activation to linear? By removing the nonlinearlity, I want to implement a first-order infinite-impulse-response (IIR) filter with a differentiable parameter and integrate it into my model for end-to-end learning. I can obviously implement the filter in Pytorch but I thought using an inbuilt function may be more efficient.

Comment: You can implement an IIR filter in PyTorch using [torchaudio](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/functional.html#torchaudio.functional.lfilter).

Comment: I can but the filter parameters are not differentiable.

Comment: Hey @Reza, were you able to solve this problem? I'm interested to know

Comment: I implemented the IIR filters in PyTorch without using any built-in RNN function and defined the parameters to be optimized using torch.nn.Parameter but it was slow and messy. I switched to Keras and used Keras's SimpleRNN with activation=None and set a constraint to fix the kernel. It was faster and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the update!